# Casting List<A> to List<B> without making a new copy

Tags: c#, casting

Please observe the following code:

```
public class MyClass
{
    List<object> _List = new List<object>();

    public List<object> Objects { get { return _List; } }
    public List<string> Strings { get { return _List.Cast<string>().ToList(); } }

    public void Test()
    {
        Objects.Add ("Hello");
        // actual contents
        // Objects = object[] { "Hello" }
        // Strings = string[] { "Hello" }

        Strings.Add ("World");
        // actual contents
        // Objects = object[] { "Hello" }
        // Strings = string[] { "Hello" }

        // expected contents
        // Objects = object[] { "Hello", "World" }
        // Strings = string[] { "Hello", "World" }
    }
}
```

The code shows a class with a list of objects. The two properties expose that list as `List<object>` and `List<string>` respectively. However, since `_List.Cast<string>().ToList()` creates a COPY of the actual list, the line `Strings.Add ("World")` doesn't affect the actual list. Is there a way to ensure a CASTED REFERENCE to the actual list is returned in the `Strings` property instead of a CASTED COPY of the actual list?

Note: The code can fail when an integer is added to `Objects` and then accessed from `Strings` but that's not what I'm worried about at the moment.

**EDIT**

The original question was as follows. It was changed to avoid confusion and simplify the problem at hand. Observe the following code:

```
public abstract class Foo
{
    List<object> _List = new List<object>();
    public List<object> ListObject { get { return _List; } }
}
public class Bar : Foo
{
    public List<string> ListString
    {
        get { return ListObject.Cast<string>().ToList(); }
    }
}

Bar oBar = new Bar();
Foo oFoo = oBar;

oFoo.ListObject.Add("Item");
// oFoo.ListObject= { "Item" }
// oBar.ListString = { "Item" }

oBar.ListString.Add("NewItem");
// oFoo.ListObject= { "Item" }
// oBar.ListString = { "Item" }
```

As you can see, using the base class object works fine (an item is added to the internal list), but using the derived class object does not work. I know the reason is because casting a List to List actually creates a new copy of the list and returns that instead. I'm wondering if it is possible to write these classes such that it works both ways.

Comment: I think this is only possible with `dynamic`s, isn't it? Use a dynamic object internally...

Comment: This code compiles and works on C# 5 / .NET 4.5. So where's the problem ? Take note that when adding to ListString you are not adding to _List but to a new on-the-fly created List.

Comment: If what you are trying to do is cast `List<object>` to `List<string>` in a subclass, I would caution that is unwise at best and extremely bad programming at worst. What is your end goal?

Comment: You seem like you want to learn something and not implement production code ? Be more clear what you are wondering about?

Comment: @Vercas.. dynamic??? ummm i need to look at it cuz ive never heard of it. =)

Comment: @PetarRepac.. thats exactly the problem.. its adding to the newly created list.. i need it to add to the original list..

Comment: @AweSIM Eh, it's basically an object whose type is solved at runtime, not when compiled. I tried a few things with it...

Comment: @rmayer06.. yes im aware its bad logic.. i am faced with a situation similar to this (this is much more simplified) and im actually resorting to changing my logic.. but i was wondering if such a thing is feasible in c#..

Answer (score 3):

I was hoping that someone else would come up with a reasonably good answer to this, but the reality is that there's probably not a *good* answer to this one.

However, there are several ways to skin your average cat, many of them pretty ugly.

One ugly solution to this problem is to implement a list class that encapsulates n `List<object>` object and attempts to access the objects as whatever type you choose.  This type of proxy class can be awkward to get right, but might be a way to do what you're trying to do.

```
public class StringObjectList : IList<string>
{
    private List<object> _list;
    public StringObjectList(List<object> src)
    {
        _list = src;
    }

    // IList Implementation...

    public string this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            object obj = _list[index];
            if (obj == null)
                return null;
            return obj.ToString();
        }
        set
        {
            _list[index] = value;
        }
    }

    // ... plus 3 more IList<string> methods (IndexOf, Insert, RemoveAt)

    // ICollection<string> implementation (5 methods, 2 properties)

    // IEnumerable<string> implementation (1 method)

    // IEnumerable implementation (1 method)
}
```

Some of the implementation details are a little tricky.  Mostly though the implementations are simple proxy methods, since the underlying list is happy to accept strings as well as any other object.  The `ICollection<string>.Add` method for instance can be as simple as:

```
public void Add(string item)
{
    _list.Add(item);
}
```

Where you might have trouble is with the `IEnumerable<string>` and `IEnumerable` implementations, which might require you to create a couple of supporting classes.

Not simple, not elegant, but potentially doable.

Answer (score 2):

You can try something like this:

```
public abstract class Foo<T>
{
    List<T> _List = new List<T>();
    public List<T> ListObject { get { return _List; } }
}
public class Bar : Foo<string>
{
    public List<string> ListString
    {
        get { return ListObject; }
    }
}
```

Result:
[image]

Comment: I think the OP doesn't look for a design, but to learn about covariance. Anyway why not directly use List<string> ? Foo and Bar doesn't add any value IMO.

Comment: Daniil and Petar, please see the edited question. I feel my question was misinterpreted. =)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't like the generic solution above, you could make the `List` member abstract.

```
public abstract class Foo
{
    public abstract IList ListObject { get; }
}

public class Bar : Foo
{
    public override IList ListObject
    {
        get { return new List<string>(); }
    }
}
```

Comment: the issue here is that i need both Foo and Bar to have a list (hence making it part of the base class) but Foo should expose the list as `List<object>` and Bar as `List<string>`.. and both Foo.ListObject.Add("string") and Bar.ListObject.Add("string") should work.. this code doesnt address the following concerns..
1. both Foo and Bar return the SAME kind of list (overriding)..
2. Bar returns a new empty list everytime..

Comment: Make sure you add the requirements to your original question, if you haven't done so already.  My specialty is finding simple solutions to complex problems, and I really don't understand what you wish to accomplish here (the end goal) - if you specified that, rather than the implementation requirements, I might be able to help you more.

Comment: @rmayer06.. ive changed the question to reflect the requirements.. the end goal, ive written somewhere here, is kind of stupid and is an example of bad design.. being able to access a `List<object>` as `List<int>` when you have added some strings to it is truly bad design.. thats why im actually changing the design.. im just inquiring how to implement this bad design for the sake of learning..

Answer (score 0):

```
    public abstract class Foo<T>
    {
        public abstract IList<T> MyList { get; }
        // you can manipulate MyList in this class even if it is defined in inherited class
    }

    public class Bar : Foo<string>
    {
        private readonly IList<string> _myList = new List<string>();

        public override IList<string> MyList
        {
            get { return _myList; }
        }
    }

    [TestFixture]
    public class TestFixture1
    {
        [Test]
        public void Test()
        {
            Bar oBar = new Bar();
            Foo<string> oFoo = oBar;

            oFoo.MyList.Add("Item");
            // oFoo.ListObject= { "Item" }
            // oBar.ListString = { "Item" }

            oBar.MyList.Add("NewItem");
            // oFoo.ListObject= { "Item" }
            // oBar.ListString = { "Item" }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Petar, please see the edited question. I feel the problem was misinterpreted. =).